# Creating a simple election poll using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am struggling with this little problem. I need to poll users for election input and output the winner.

Input: Poll 10 people for their vote.
Output: Print the total votes cast as well as the winner of the election.

```
Example: 
  Election candidates are: Tom, James, Anne

  Vote #1: <Anne>
  Vote #2: <Anne>
  Vote #3: <James>
  Vote #4: <Tom>
  Vote #5: <Tom>
  Vote #6: <Anne>
  Vote #7: <Anne>
  Vote #8: <James>
  Vote #9: <James>
  Vote #10: <Anne>

 RESULTS....

  Vote Summary:
  Anne - 5 vote(s)
  James - 3 vote(s)
  Tom - 2 vote(s)

  WINNER: Anne!
```

I am thinking about using the each iterator to fill all the Votes with users' inputs for candidates. Like this:

```
(1..10).each do|i| 
puts "Vote##{i}: " + "<"+gets.chomp+">"
end
```

But then, I don't know how to find the total votes for each candidate. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you require the results to be printed in order of votes?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the entered values into a hash and then process the results:

```
results = (1..10).each.with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |i, hash|
  name = gets.chomp
  hash[name] += 1
  puts "Vote##{i}: <#{name}>"
end

puts "RESULTS...."
puts "Votes Summary:"

results.each do |name, votes|
  puts "#{name} - #{votes} vote(s)"
end

winner = results.max_by(&:last)

puts "WINNER: #{winner}!"
```

Comment: Could also do `results.max_by(&:last)` instead of `results.to_a.max { |a, b|  a[1] <=> b[1] }`